# Why is open declared in fcntl.h, while close is declared in unistd.h?

Tags: unix, posix

In POSIX, why is the open system call declared in fcntl.h, while the close system call is declared in unistd.h? I presume this is a historical artifact, but this pair strikes me as especially odd since you often need to close after open.

Comment: May or may not be related, but it is perhaps useful to note that there are quite a few routines other than `open()` that return things that should eventually be passed to `close()`. So in that sense, `close()` has a much wider application than `open()` does...

Comment: That makes sense. Perhaps in the early days of UNIX, when everything was a file (I wonder if that was ever true), perhaps they were in the same header file. Then after other descriptor based APIs came around (e.g., socket) it made more sense to have the generic file descriptor routines (read/write/close) in unistd.h with the APIs that create the various descriptor types scattered about.

Comment: The `unistd.h` header file is newer than `fcntl.h`.  I don't think there was a unistd.h before POSIX.  It used to be a real bear to figure out where (if?) things were declared.  I can't be sure.  It was a long time ago.

Comment: This may be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47517088/19647418

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As previously pointed out, sockets and pipes also get passed to close.  But probably the original reason is that open needs flags like O_RDONLY that are defined in fcntl.h, so you might as well put the prototype in that file.

Comment: As no authoritative answer is likely forthcoming, I'll accept this since it at least seems reasonable.