# What is full name of fcntl Unix/Linux system call

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, system-calls, fcntl

Man page of `fcntl` tell its used for manipulating file descriptors. But this name is not easy to remember. Knowing its full name will help in remember this system call name and its use. I tried to find on internet but could not get anything except man pages.

Please someone tell what is full name or origin of name of fcntl.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From POSIX, it is [**F**ile **C**o**nt**ro**l**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html):

> **NAME**
>
> `fcntl` - **f**ile **c**o**nt**ro**l**

---

There is a related system call, `ioctl`, i.e. **I**nput-**O**utput **C**on**t**ro**l**. The difference between the 2 is that `fcntl` modifies the file descriptor / file description, whereas `ioctl` controls behaviour of the input/output device behind the file description.

Comment: Now, you just have to remember if it's `fcntl`, `fctl` or `fctrl` :p

Comment: It's the one that sounds the most like it was written in *Nahuatl* with vowels omitted.